# Which search criteria is used to search for emails with attachements?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm trying to do a compound search using the Query Builder in Outlook, and one of the criteria I need is an equivalent to "Has Attachments" in the quick and advanced searches.

Which field/search criteria would give me this?

Comment: Try using a search folder instead.. I don't think it's inherently an option for query builder. Or try `hasattachment:yes` [KB](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) suggests it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Query Builder appends its conditions to the main ones. For example, you can set **Only items with one or more attachments** on **More Choices** tab and then configure more conditions on **Query Builder** tab. You'll find that it works flawless.

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2010 you just need to type "Attachment" (type in, not choose) and then choose "Equals" and "Yes".

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Read the accepted answer you did not give more information

Comment: Just an FYI - This solution didn't work in 2016. `The field specified cannot be found.`

Comment: I can confirm this works OK in Outlook 2010 (and is much more flexible / useful than the accepted answer)